# "Expression expected" and "Cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

I have recently taken some OOP lessons in java. While implementing it today, I came across " cannot find symbol" error in my program. In the suggestions on the side it says, "expression expected". I have been trying to figure out my mistake for a while now but no luck has met me so far. Can someone help me here?

This is my main class:

```
public class Slotmachine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int plays;

        SlotMac machine[] = new SlotMac[3];    
                                                 // error seems to be somewhere here!
        SlotMac[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
        SlotMac[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
        SlotMac[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);

        plays = machine.firstmachine(machine[0]);
    }
}
```

My other class:

```
public class SlotMac {

    int win_plays;
    int times_played;
    int quarters;

    public SlotMac(int times_played, int win_plays, int quarters) {
        this.win_plays = win_plays;
        this.times_played = times_played;
        this.quarters = quarters;
    }

    public int firstmachine(SlotMac one) {
        return plays;
    }
}
```

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SlotMac
  location: class Slotmachine

Same error bunch of time.

Comment: do not post duplicate questions, edit the one you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532713/cannot-find-symbol-error-when-compiling/23532749#23532749

Answer (score 2):

You should be using variable name of the array instead of classname.

```
machine[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
machine[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
machine[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);
```

I see you fixed the other `firsmachine()` related things

Answer (score 0):

you are creating array of machines so change

```
SlotMac[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
SlotMac[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
SlotMac[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);
```

to

```
machine[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
    machine[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
    machine[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);
```

Comment: thanks and I think I am not calling the method the right way? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SLotMac[0]`, it should be `machine[0]`, and so on…

I didnot understand your comment. But here is a sample code

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int plays;

SlotMac machine[] = new SlotMac[3];    
                                         // error seems to be somewhere here!
machine[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
machine[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
machine[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);

plays= machine[0].firstmachine(machine[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this to:

```
    SlotMac[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
    SlotMac[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
    SlotMac[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);
```

this:

```
machine[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);    
machine[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
machine[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you imported the same class?

you need to import the class before you use it in code

so import it using import statement

`import package.name.SlotMac` into `SlotMachine.java` file