# Cannot find symbol error when compiling.

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

Can someone help me find the error in my program? When I compile it, it gives the cannot find symbol error. I have been playing around with it for a while but cant seem to grasp my mistake.

My main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int plays;

    SlotMac machine[] = new SlotMac[3];

    machine[0] = new SlotMac(3,35,30);
    machine[1] = new SlotMac(10,100,60);
    machine[2] = new SlotMac(4,10,9);

    plays= firstmachine(machine[0]);
    System.out.println(plays);
```

My other class:

```
public class SlotMac {

    int win_plays, plays;
    int times_played;
    int quarters;


    public SlotMac(int times_played, int win_plays, int quarters) {

        this.win_plays= win_plays;
        this.times_played= times_played;
        this.quarters= quarters;

    }

    public int firstmachine() {
        return plays;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have asked 5 questions but havent accepted any answers.Reward the person by accepting answer of that person whose answer solved your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Expression expected" and "Cannot find symbol" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532132/expression-expected-and-cannot-find-symbol-error)

Answer (score 1):

there is no method `firstmachine(SlotMac obj)`

so when you say `firstmachine(machine[0]);` it will try to search the same method in the same class, which it will not find.

you need to call the method like following

```
machine[0].firstmachine();
```

Comment: paste the error! which symbol is it not able to find?

Comment: you need an import of the class SlotMac in SlotMachine class i referred the second question you asked!